# Are OData query options executed on server or client?

Tags: database, odata, sapui5, hana

I am trying to obtain a sub-list of items in a SAP Hana database. If I use query option `$filter` e.g. `/subscripor?$filter=age%20eq%2025` will the database return all the entries in the table and then oData will filter on client? or is this filter will be executed on the server? Can anybody point me to the documentation where this is clarify?

I've seen the [OData documentation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#ServiceOperationParameters) but doesn't specify where these query options are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a degree of control over this and there are certain conditions attached to being able to perform the options locally.
Please refer to the documentation [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode/properties) for the detailed info.

To give you a sample use scenario within the context of a Table control see below:

```
<Table noDataText="no data" id="table0" visibleRowCount="10" threshold="15"
    rows="{ path: 'yourModel>/yourDataSet', parameters: {operationMode: 'Server'} }">
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Out of curiosity, what if the service is not consumed by a UI5 app? Say if I just use the browser or postman.

Comment: How would your browser / postman know what to do with an OData request? The server is responsible for fulfilling all requirements made in the request URL.

Comment: postman will ALWAYS engage directly with the server. A browser will interpret the code within the context it is being executed. If the context forces a server call that's what you'll get - a server call. - hope that kind of makes sense